# how do you divide a smaller number with a bigger number C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a program in C++ that is trying to work out someones percent based on their mark in their test, I have only been programming in this language for a few days and I wrote this code as a simplified version of my original one, if you can help then thank you. (the problem I am getting is that the program is printing 0 as the total percent)

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    
    int totalPercent;
    int totalMarks;
    
    cout << "what is the total Marks" << endl;
    cin >> totalMarks;
    
    totalPercent = totalMarks/300 * 100;
    
    cout << "the total percent is " << totalPercent << "%" << endl;
}
```

Comment: This is known as `integer division`, two integers divided by each other will always result in an integer. You could use a real type like `float` or `double` or you could change the order of operations so that the multiplication is done first and then the integer division.

Comment: Check this link to learn how variables work, the INT type will only give you Integers:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/

Comment: `-5 / 2 = -2`,
 `5 / 2 =  2`, `-5.0 / 2 = -2.5`,
 `5.0 / 2 =  2.5`
C++ always "truncates" towards 0 (eg, the decimal places get removed)

Answer (score 4):

You are effected by integer division. Two integers division always result in an integer. So

1. 220 / 300 results 0
2. 301/300 results 1
3. 632/300 results 2

I hope you got the point. Now to fix this issue, either you need to change one of the variable as float / double or change the order of operands.

**1st approach:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int totalPercent;
    float totalMarks;
    
    cout << "what is the total Marks" << endl;
    cin >> totalMarks;
    
    totalPercent = totalMarks/300 * 100;
    
    cout << "the total percent is " << totalPercent << "%" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**2nd approach (change the order of operands):**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int totalPercent;
    int totalMarks;
    
    cout << "what is the total Marks" << endl;
    cin >> totalMarks;
    
    totalPercent = totalMarks * 100 / 300;
    
    cout << "the total percent is " << totalPercent << "%" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, you can just do this: `totalPercent = totalMarks/300.0 * 100;`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Yes :)

Answer (score 0):

The program returns the int datatype 0 because the result is comma, change it to float.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

   float totalPercent;
    float totalMarks;

    cout << "what is the total Marks" << endl;
    cin >> totalMarks;

    totalPercent = (totalMarks / 300) * 100;

    cout << "the total percent is " << '%'  << totalPercent<< endl;
   
    ::getchar();
}
```

Comment: What does "the result is comma" mean?

Comment: İt is mean  result "16.666667" vs

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

float totalPercent;
float totalMarks;

cout << "what is the total Marks" << endl;
cin >> totalMarks;

totalPercent = totalMarks/300 * 100;

cout << "the total percent is " << totalPercent << "%" << endl;
}
```

Change it to float and it will work